# Setting shortcuts keys in specific modes in Emacs (e.g. ido)

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, flyspell, ido

I have two problems which are somewhat related I believe:

1) In IDO I'd like to change ido-restrict-to-matches to samething else than <kbd>C-SPC</kbd> or <kbd>C-@</kbd>. Unfortunately I do not know how to tell emacs that I want a different shortcut (say <kbd>C-0</kbd>).

2) I'd like to protect my <kbd>C-;</kbd> but whenever flyspell-mode is running it overtakes <kbd>C-;</kbd>. My definition is in .emacs as:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-;") 'mark-paragraph)
```

but apparently flyspell overwrites this... (although even then, if I look in the help <kbd>M-h k C-;</kbd> it does say `mark-paragraph`)

Could somebody please tell me how to bind/unbind keys in these conditions? It has to work without modifying ido.el and flyspell.el and re-building, right?

Thanks very much!

Comment: @Trey Jackson: thank you for the mark up - now I see how it is done :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flyspell provides a customization for the `C-;` binding, so you can either `M-x customize RET flyspell-auto-correct-binding RET` or put something like this in your `~/.emacs`:

```
(setq flyspell-auto-correct-binding (kbd "C-~")) ; or a binding of your choice
```

As for `ido`, your question is slightly confusing, because it implies there are times when you're using ido outside the minibuffer...

The documentation in ido.el contains the following advice:

```
;; To modify the keybindings, use the ido-setup-hook.  For example:
;;(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook 'ido-my-keys)
;;
;;(defun ido-my-keys ()
;;  "Add my keybindings for ido."
;;  (define-key ido-completion-map " " 'ido-next-match)
;;  )
```

Using that knowledge, you can change the key bindings like this in your own "ido-my-keys" function:

```
(define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-SPC") nil)
(define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-@") nil)
(define-key ido-completion-map (kbd "C-0") 'ido-restrict-to-matches)
```

There's an additional ido hook specifically for the minibuffer, too, but it's not clear why you would need that: `ido-minibuffer-setup-hook`.

Comment: Thanks! It works!! I actually did look into ido.el... but missed this part. Also flyspell is now OK. Thanks!